# tangent of line intersects curve at 2 points

Tags: functions

> Function $y=x^3-9x$ has tangent at $(3,0)$ that intersects the curve at $2$ points.

The equation of the tangent: $y=18x -54$

How do I find the other intersection points? Do I solve simultaneous equations of the 2 equations?

Comment: In English term "intersection point" is adequate for tangent point also, that is tangent point is also intersection point. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I solve simulatanous equations of the 2 equation?

Yes

Furthermore, you already know that $x=3$ is a double solution.

You get $18x-54=y=x^3-9x$. Simplify: $x^3-27x+54=0$. Take out $x-3$: $x^3-27x+54 = (x-3)(x^2+3x-18)$. Now solve $x^2+3x-18=0$.

Comment: You can take out $x-3$ twice because $x=3$ is a double solution.

Comment: Yes I know, but there should be some thinking left over to OP

Comment: thank you I edited that